# java selenium webdriver span class

Tags: java, html, css

i cant seem to get the data i need

i used some xpaths, and some cssSelectors

how do i access this kind of "span" data

i get the concept of xpath and cssSeletors but i cant get the data.

how do i access the data in a span tag that has a class name that has a certain beginning ,
like "oddsValue"and then some other parameters.

like for example "oddsValue_9312e7"

oddsValue is always same but _9312e7 changes every time

```
<span class="oddsValue___1euLZeq odds-wrap up ">1.50</span>
```

how i get the 1.50?

kind regards